# Carousel seating problem including girls and boys

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

So there is this problem

A carousel has eight seats, each representing a different animal.  Eight girls are seated on the carousel facing forward $($each  girl looks at another girl's back$)$.  In how many ways can the girls change seats so that each has a different girl in front of her?  How does the problem change if all the seats are identical?

So I was wondering whether this is a circular permutation problem or just a linear one and how can you tell?  Would you have to use Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to solve this problem?

Comment: since each seat represent a different animal, is it really circular permutation?

Comment: I would argue that it is not a "circular permutation problem" for the original phrasing because the animals are distinct and presumably a girl's experience "changes" depending on which animal she rides.  You could arrange the girls in a line if you wish.  Keep in mind though that the girl at the  front of the line is looking at the back of the girl at the end of the line (*or vice versa depending on how you lined them up*)

Comment: Where are the boys in the problem?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I believe the person who answered mean girls instead of boys.

Comment: The answer is not right, it answer a another question int this [file]( https://www.math.ksu.edu/~zlin/m510/hw6.pdf), and origin question answer is 13000, 1625, Later I have free time that I can explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each seat represents a different animal, the question is not a circular permutation question rather a linear permutations. We will name the girls by the numbers as they sit first time so that $1$ faces $5, 2$ faces $6, 3$ faces $7$ and $4$ faces $8$. We use inclusion-exclusion principle. Let $S$ be the set of all permutations of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$ and

$T_1$ be the set of permutations in S such that $1$ faces $5$;

$T_2$ be the set of permutations in S such that $2$ faces $6$;

$T_3$ be the set of permutations in S such that $3$ faces $7$;

$T_4$ be the set of permutations in S such that $4$ faces $8$.

Note that $|S| = 8!$. To compute $|T_1|$, seat $1$, there are $8$ ways Then sit $5$ to the opposite of $1$ (only one way). Then seat the remaining $6$ girls. Then $|T_1| = 8\cdot 6!$. Similarly, $|T_2| = |T_3| = |T_4| = 8 \cdot 6!$. To compute $|T_1\cap T_2|$, seat $1$ and $5$ first $(8$ ways$)$, then seat $2$ and $6$ by just seating $2 ( 6$ has to face $2)$. There are $6$ choices and $4!$ ways to seat the remaining $4$ girls Thus, $|T_1\cap T_2|=8\cdot4\cdot4!$.

Similarly, $T_i\cap T_j|=8\cdot4\cdot4!\forall i\ne j$. In $T_1\cap T_2\cap T_3$ first seat $1$ and $5 (8$ ways$)$ then seat $2$ and $6$, $(6$ ways) followed by seating $3$ and $7 (4$ ways$)$ then remaining $2$ girls $(2$ ways$)$. So, $T_1\cap T_2\cap T_3$ and any other intersections of three sets have $8\cdot6\cdot4\cdot2!$ ways.

Similarly, $|T_1\cap T_2\cap T_3\cap T_4|=6\cdot4\cdot2$.

Thus by the inclusion-exclusion principle, the number of
ways to change the seating so no boy faces the same person is$$8!-\dbinom41\cdot8\cdot6!+\dbinom42\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4!-\dbinom43\cdot6\cdot4\cdot2!+\dbinom44\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4\cdot2$$

If all seats are identical, the question becomes a circular permutation question. Now we let $S$
be the set of all circular permutations of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$ and

$T_1$ be the set of permutations in S such that $1$ faces $5$;

$T_2$ be the set of permutations in S such that $2$ faces $6$;

$T_3$ be the set of permutations in S such that $3$ faces $7$;

$T_4$ be the set of permutations in S such that $4$ faces $8$.

Note that $|S|=\dfrac{8!}{8}=7!$. To calculate $|T_1|$, , seat $2$, and $5$ first (only one way), then seat the
remaining $6$ girls. Then $|T_1=6!$. Similarly, $|T_2|=|T_3|=|T_4|=6!$. To compute $|T_1\cap T_2$, seat $1$, and $5$ first, then seat $2$ and $6$ by just seating $2 ($then $6$ has to face $2)$, there are $6$ choices and $4!$ ways to seat the remaining $4$ girls. Thus $|T_1\cap T_2|=6\cdot4!$.

Similarly, $|T_i\cap T_j|=6\cdot4!\forall i\ne j$. In $T_1\cap T_2\cap T_3$ first seat $1$ and $5 ($one way$)$ then seat $2$ and $6$, $(6$ ways$)$ followed
seating $3$ and $7 (4$ ways$)$ then remaining $2$ girls (two ways). Thus $T_1\cap T_2\cap T_3$ and any other
intersections of three sets have $6 · 4 · 2!$ elements. Similarly, $|T_1\cap T_2\cap T_3\cap T_4|=6\cdot4\cdot2$.

Thus by the inclusion-exclusion principle, the number of ways to change the seating so no boy faces the
same person is $$7!-\dbinom41 6!+\dbinom42 6\cdot4!-\dbinom 43 6\cdot4\cdot2+6\cdot4\cdot2\cdot1=2880$$

Note that each of the numbers we computed for identical seats are just the numbers of those with different animals divided by $8$. This reflects that the first case (seat with different animals) the seating are linear permutations, while the identical cases are circular permutations and the total numbers differed by a factor of $8$.

Comment: I think you mean girls instead of boys, but the logic is sound!

Comment: @Itsnhantransitive I did it in a hurry and didn't notice that. It is fixed now.